# stop wildfly sending console output to server logs

Tags: logging, log4j, wildfly

I am using `wildfly 10` and everything appearing in console(e.g. System.out.println("") output) is being written to `server.log` file. 
I want to see only `log4j` logs in `server.log` file, so how can i stop sending console output to `server.log` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "only log4j"?

Comment: Assume my app code has the following statements: logger.error("some error") and System.out.println("something") (stdout is console in my case so this will be printed in console). In my server.log i see both outputs not only logger's log, because somehow wildfly sends all the console output to his server.log. I don't want the output of the second statement to appear in server.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `stdout` logger to `WARN`:

```
<logger category="stdout">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
```

This will prevent `System.out.println(...)` to appear in your `server.log`. But it will also not appear on console, because Wildfly replaces the `System.out` `PrintStream` by its own implementation (see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.stdio/jboss-stdio/1.0.0.CR3/org/jboss/stdio/StdioContext.java#StdioContext.install%28%29)), hence you can only suppress it for all handlers or activate it for all.

Comment: You could also just change the `use-parent-handlers=false` and assign the `stdout` logger to the console handler.